# django views connecting to model and urls

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I am writing my first views in Django.  I have spent countless hours trying to figure this out.  One of my views appears in the web page, but the other one that I am trying to retrieve data from the database is not.  I've used the python shell to see if the code works and it does.  The following is my model, view, my urls, and template.  Additionally, any documentation websites would be great too - or books.  thanks all.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Bee_hive(models.Model):
    gid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    hive_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_hive_death = models.DateField()
    date_hive_created = models.DateField()
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hive_title
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import datetime

from inventory.models import Bee_hive

def index(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    context = {'current_date': now}
    return render(request, 'inventory/index.html', context)

def hive_names(request):
    titles = Bee_hive.objects.all()
    context = {'titles': titles}
    return render(request, 'inventory/index.html', context)
```

My template contains the following:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, David!</p>
        It is now {{ current_date }}.
        <p>The hive name is: {{ titles }} </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from inventory import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^$', views.hive_names, name='hive_names'),

)
```

This is my result:

```
Hello, David!

It is now Jan. 18, 2015, 7:08 a.m..
The hive name is:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set different urls to different views:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^hive-names/$', views.hive_names, name='hive_names'),
)
```

Comment: I tried this approach and still the same result.  I'm trying to figure out where the "hive-names" in your suggestion would be referenced.

Comment: @david You can see your `title` object by visiting `127.0.0.1:8000/hive-names`

Comment: okay Raja.  that worked!  thanks!  feeling really brainless right now.  I've got some work to do so that I receive my views in one page.  As a newbie, feeling really confused and frustrated right now.